# How to check if TextField has overflown? And how to apply autoresize?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I'm building a DropDownMenu and the composable showing the current selected item is a `TextField`. I would like for the text to be resized if the selected element is too long, but I can't seem to find a way do so. I've searched how to autoresize in Jetpack Compose, but every solution I've found requires to know when the text has overflown, which is something I can't seem to do using `TextField`. In fact, every solution uses `Text` or `BasicTextField`, both of which have the `onTextLayout` option, but no one is using `TextField`, which has no `onTextLayout` option. Note that I cannot change composable because `TextField` has the `trailingIcon` option which is useful in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but I hope this solution will help. We can set the options to select as a hashmap of strings and their widths. If the `fontSize` of your `Text` composables and the `TextField` are the same, you can easily calculate width of each string on screen using the `onGloballyPositioned()` extension for a `Modifier`.

```
val selectionOptions = mutableMapOf(
    "Short" to 0.dp,
    "A longer text" to 0.dp,
    "Some very, very long text" to 0.dp
)
val density = LocalDensity.current
val selectedItem = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val textFieldWidth = remember { mutableStateOf(10.dp) }
Column(
    Modifier
        .padding(top = 100.dp, start = 30.dp, end = 30.dp)
) {
    selectionOptions.forEach {
        Text(
            text = it.key,
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    selectedItem.value = it.key
                    textFieldWidth.value = it.value
                }
                .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                    // assign width to each option in the map
                    selectionOptions[it.key] = with(density) {
                        coordinates.boundsInParent().width.toDp()
                    }
                }
        )
    }
    TextField(
        value = selectedItem.value,
        onValueChange = { value -> selectedItem.value = value },
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(textFieldWidth.value + 40.dp)
            .defaultMinSize(
                minWidth = 0.dp,
                minHeight = TextFieldDefaults.MinHeight
            )
    )
}
```

It is not an elegant implementation, but I think it is fairly simple.
Check out the screen recording to see whether it's what you want: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VoBuS5XV15UqBOeIoiCult8JxsmF5S4d/view?usp=sharing